# Corda - Register and Listen to Handler/Responder Flows

Tags: kotlin, corda

Consider the following Corda flow pair:

**Sender Flow**

```kotlin
class SendFlow(val message: String, val session: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Boolean>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): Boolean {
        return session.sendAndReceive<Boolean>(message)
    }

    @StartableByRPC
    @StartableByService
    @InitiatingFlow(version = 1)
    class Initiator(val message: String, val recipient: Party) : FlowLogic<Boolean>() {
    
        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): Boolean {
            return subFlow(SendFlow(message, initiateFlow(party)))
        }
    }
}
```

**Receiver Flow**

```kotlin
class ReceiveFlow(val session: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<String>() {
    
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): String {
        val result = session.receive<String>().unwrap { it }
        session.send(result == "Hello, World!")
        return result
    }

    @InitiatedBy(SendFlow.Initator::class)
    class Handler(val session: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<String>() {
    
        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): String {
            return subFlow(ReceiveFlow(session))
        }
    }
}
```

It's well documented and trivial to obtain a result from an initiating flow over RPC...

```kotlin
rpc
    .startFlow(SendFlow::Initiator, "Hello, World!", someParty)
    .returnValue
    .getOrThrow() // expect to be true
```

How would I register something to listen to the output of an `@InitiatedBy(...)` flow? - That is to say, I want to be able to observe received messages on from the receiving node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`stateMachinesFeed`](https://api.corda.net/api/corda-os/4.7/html/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.messaging/-corda-r-p-c-ops/state-machines-feed.html) RPC API to observe new flows as they are created and their results when they complete.

This API is can be used in the following way (code in Kotlin):

```
val rpcClient: CordaRpcOps // initialise this properly depending on your environment
rpcClient.stateMachinesFeed().updates.subscribe {
    when(it) {
        is StateMachineUpdate.Added -> {
            val flowId = it.id
            val flowInfo = it.stateMachineInfo
            // code to react to new flow initiation
        }
        is StateMachineUpdate.Removed -> {
            val flowId = it.id
            val flowResult = it.result
            flowResult.doOnSuccess(Consumer { result -> /* code to process result of successful completion */ })
            flowResult.doOnFailure(Consumer { error -> /* code to process error from failed completion */ })
        }
    }
}
```